# How to port forwarding in GitHub action VM

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there any way to port forwarding, I saw ufw command work with sudo but I can't connect with server via ip and allow port with ufw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, using any port forwarder is good choice eg ngrok etc otherwise there's no other way to port forwards, I got from GitHub forum